# How to reindex_axis Pandas Panel to MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, panel, multi-index

I have a 3D panel data.
I am unable to reindex it to a multi index along level 2.

I have created the multi index 'mind'.

```
import pandas as pd

mind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Consumer,Cyclical','Industrial','Software'], ['Retail','MiscellaneousManufactur','Technology'], ['AZO','AZZ','AZPN']],names=['sec','sub','ticker'])

dfclose = pd.DataFrame([[1.1,2.1,3.1],[1.2,2.2,3.2]], index=['2013-09-02','2013-09-03'], columns=['AZO','AZZ','AZPN'])
dfmean = dfclose - dfclose.mean()

pdata2 = pd.Panel({'close':dfclose, 'mean':dfmean})
pdata2.minor_axis.name='ticker'
pdata3=pdata2.reindex_axis(mind,axis=2,level='ticker')
```

But the pdata3 is not getting mapped to the new multi index and giving NaN.

Comment: which version of pandas are you using? Can you show what you mean with NaN?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in 0.12 (and will be fixed in 0.13).
A workaround is not to reindex after, but to use the MultiIndex when creating dfclose:

```
dfclose = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1], [1.2, 2.2, 3.2]],
                           index=['2013-09-02','2013-09-03'],
                           columns=mind)
dfmean = dfclose - dfclose.mean()
pdata2 = pd.Panel({'close':dfclose, 'mean':dfmean})
pdata2.minor_axis.name='ticker'

In [11]: pdata2.iloc[0]
Out[12]: 
sec         Consumer,Cyclical               Industrial    Software
sub                    Retail  MiscellaneousManufactur  Technology
ticker                    AZO                      AZZ        AZPN
2013-09-02                1.1                      2.1         3.1
2013-09-03                1.2                      2.2         3.2
```

Another option is to just use a DataFrame:

```
In [12]: pd.concat([dfmean, dfclose], axis=1, keys=['dfmean' ,'dfclose'])
Out[12]: 
                       dfmean                                                 dfclose                                       
sec         Consumer,Cyclical               Industrial    Software  Consumer,Cyclical               Industrial    Software 
sub                    Retail  MiscellaneousManufactur  Technology             Retail  MiscellaneousManufactur  Technology  
ticker                    AZO                      AZZ        AZPN                AZO                      AZZ        AZPN 
2013-09-02              -0.05                    -0.05       -0.05                1.1                      2.1         3.1  
2013-09-03               0.05                     0.05        0.05                1.2                      2.2         3.2
```

Comment: Strange, with pandas 0.12 I am also getting NaNs: just in the dataframe in ``Out [12]`` all values are NaNs

Comment: But in master I am getting the same as you

Comment: my bad, the workaround still works in 0.12, but was bug in reindex?

Comment: Apparantly it was a bug (but only for panel, with a dataframe `dfclose.reindex_axis(mind,axis=1,level='ticker')` it also works in 0.12), but it seems fixed now!

Comment: in 0.12 this was not passing on the *level* param when reindexing, not really sure why though (in core/panel.py)